# nested transactions not supported hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-7

I am using hibernate in my project : config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">name</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">passwd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
    <mapping resource="db/Sanitka.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="db/Sanitari.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="db/Nemocnica.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and my helper file looks like this

```
public class helper {
    private static Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    public static List<Sanitka> getNemocnicas() {
    List<Nemocnica> filmList = null;
    org.hibernate.Transaction  tx = null;
    try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery ("from Nemocnica");
        filmList = (List<Nemocnica>) q.list();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filmList;
}
    public static List<Nemocnica> getSanitkas() {
    List<Nemocnica> filmList = null;
     org.hibernate.Transaction  tx = null;
    try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery ("from Sanitka");
        filmList = (List<Nemocnica>) q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filmList;
}
}
```

I am building restful api , the

```
/nemocnica
```

route invokes getNemocnicas()

and `/sanitkas` route invokes getSanitkas()

What is problem is that when i go to `/nemocnica` getNemocnicas() is invoked and return query from database , however when after that i want to go to `/sanitkas`

it throws

> org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

error. I read that it is bcs i am not closing session from previous transaction. But when i added

```
if( tx != null)
     tx.commit()
```

before return statement in those methods , it threw this error :

> org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

What is the optimal way to close transaction then?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why are you manually trying to start a transaction?  That should be the job of the app container, no? Just take the beginTransaction() calls out. Also, your SQL is a query, not DML, no?